# how to use a for loop in ReactJS to update the state on meeting some condition? loops are not requiring to traverse from every element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am having trouble using for loop.
forloop increasing the count if the condition is met.
Below is my code:

```
 class CountWalls extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                leftcount : 0,
                rightcount : 0
            }
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            const arr = [4, 1, 1, 3, 2];
            let max = 0;
            max = Math.max(...arr);
            if(arr[0] <= max){ this.setleft() }
            if(arr[arr.length - 1] <= max){ this.setright() }    
    
            for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
                if(arr[0] == max) break;
                if(arr[i]<=max && arr[i] > arr[i-1]){
                  this.setState({leftcount: this.state.leftcount + 1}); 
                 }
            }   
            for(var i = arr.length-2; i >=0; i--){
              if(arr[arr.length-1]==max) break;
              if(arr[i]<= max && arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
                this.setState({rightcount: this.state.rightcount + 1}); 
            }   
          }
        }
        setright = () =>{ 
            this.setState({rightcount: 1});    
        }
        setleft = () =>{ 
                this.setState({leftcount: 1});
        } 
        render(){
            return(
                <>
                 <h2>Right count: {this.state.rightcount}</h2>
                 <h2>Left count: {this.state.leftcount}</h2>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

Output is: Right count:1, Left Count:1 because the loop didn't run and values are 1 only as set in function setRight and setLeft.
map, filter method returns a new array which is not required here. how should I make the state object count to increment in condition?

Comment: are you trying to count number of elements in the left and right based on position of max number?

Comment: The output of your app doesn't unexpected according to your for loops and if statements

Comment: Both of your for loops was broken by these conditions `if(arr[0] == max) break;` `if(arr[arr.length-1]==max) break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop actually executes twice. However, you need to be aware that `setState` is asynchronous.

That means that when you're calling `this.state.rightcount` inside the loop the value is still `0` because the `setState` has not completed yet.

You can fix this by using variables to store the `rightCount` and `leftCount` and only calling `setState` once.

```js
class CountWalls extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          leftcount : 0,
          rightcount : 0
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      const arr = [4, 1, 1, 3, 2];
      let max = Math.max(...arr);
      let leftCount = 0;
      let rightCount = 0;

      if(arr[0] <= max){ leftCount = 1; }
      if(arr[arr.length - 1] <= max){ rightCount = 1; }

      for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
          if(arr[0] === max) break;
          if(arr[i]<=max && arr[i] > arr[i-1]){
              leftCount++;
          }
      }
      for(let i = arr.length-2; i >=0; i--){
          if(arr[arr.length-1] === max) break;
          if(arr[i]<= max && arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
              rightCount++;
          }
      }

      this.setState({
        rightcount: rightCount,
        leftcount: leftCount,
      });
  }

  render(){
      return(
          <>
           <h2>Right count: {this.state.rightcount}</h2>
           <h2>Left count: {this.state.leftcount}</h2>
          </>
      );
  }
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0